# Why gitlab runner cannot run jobs on the 3Gb Digital ocean servers?

Tags: digital-ocean, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running my rails tests on 4Gb Digital ocean servers using gitlab runner. After I changed runner size to 3Gb and restarted coordinator it stopped to run the builds at all

```
# /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

[[runners]]
  ...
  [runners.machine]
    ...
    MachineOptions = [
      "digitalocean-size=3gb" # before there was 4gb
       ...
    ]
```

No Digital ocean servers are created and jobs show the following information:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.5.1 
  on <Project name> build coordinator <ID>
...
```

Nothing happens and in the end job fails with timeout

Is it possible to reduce Digital ocean job runner size from 4Gb to 3Gb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On January 16, 2018 Digital ocean introduced [new droplet plans](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/changelog/api-v2/new-size-slugs-for-droplet-plan-changes/). Droplet slug names were changed accordingly. To use 3Gb servers to run your builds you must have the following line in your `MachineOptions`:

```
# /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
[[runners]]
  ...
  [runners.machine]
    ...
    MachineOptions = [
      "digitalocean-size=s-1vcpu-3gb"
       ...
    ]
```